# How to unlink a Microsoft account from a Windows account in Windows 1903

Tags: windows, microsoft-account

It used to be possible to disconnect a linked Microsoft account from a local account from the "Accounts" settings page, but Microsoft in their wisdom have removed this option.  I accidentally linked my Microsoft account (something I don't want as I have no desire for MS to be copying my account info to the cloud).  How do I go back to having a local account?

Comment: It wont be long before Microsoft will only allow Microsoft account!>>>>>>>>>>https://www.howtogeek.com/442609/confirmed-windows-10-setup-now-prevents-local-account-creation/

Comment: Agree it's a duplicate and have added the new answer there.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen a fair few people expressing similar frustration online.  Since I've found the answer, it seems wise to document it here.  The link is, of course, stored in the registry.  It can be deleted by launching "regedit", navigating to

HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities

And by deleting the subkey with your account name in it.

Answer (score -1):

I have a Microsoft Account with V1903. Open Settings, Accounts and "Sign In with Local Account"  Same in V19H2 Insider.  Here is a decent tutorial for changing accounts. Microsoft Accounts work very well also so I do not really recommend it. My screen shot shows the basics.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-switch-local-account-microsoft-account-windows-10

[image]

Comment: This does not work in recent versions of Windows.  The "Sign In with a local account instead" option has been removed.

Comment: It is working in V1903 and V19H2 (Insider version not yet out for most users)

Comment: I am on 1903 and it is not working for me.  An internet search will confirm that others have the same problem.   I can't say why it is working for you, but there are definitely some systems on which it is not working.